# Setting a inner document attribute in MongoDB with Java API

Tags: java, mongodb

I am struggling to figure out the correct way to update/insert a new attribute into an inner document.   Everything i am trying is just not working.

```
{ "a" : true, 
  "b" : {
     "bb" : true
  }
}
```

What is my Java code for say setting "cc" in the "b" structure?  The Java API doesn't seem to support the dot.notation.

--- found the answer ---

After much fiddling around i figured it out.

```
BasicDBObject dbobj = new BasicDBObject("b.cc", true);
BasicDBObject b = new BasicDBObject("$set", dbobj );
```

The dot.notation does work and you have to fully qualify the full key path

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().
  push("$set").
  append("b.cc", true).
  get
```